# VideoSupportFragment resizing cropps the video

Tags: android, android-videoview, leanback

When I try to animate the size-changing of the VideoSupportFragment the video itself is cropped.

Animation code for reference:

```
val params = playbackVideoFragment.layoutParams

val resizeXanim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(playerWidth, containerWidth * scaleX).apply {
    addUpdateListener {
        params .width = (it.animatedValue as Float).toInt()
    }
}

val resizeYanim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(playerHeight, containerHeight * scaleY).apply {
    addUpdateListener {
       params .height = (it.animatedValue as Float).toInt()
    }
}

val paramsAnim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 100).apply {
    addUpdateListener { playbackVideoFragment.layoutParams = params }
}

AnimatorSet().apply {
    playTogether(resizeXanim, resizeYanim, paramsAnim)
    duration = ANIMATION_DURATION_MS
    start()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a while a figured out that commenting super method **onVideoSizeChanged** of **VideoSupportFragment** solves the issue.

```
class CustomVideoFragment : VideoSupportFragment() {
    ...
    override fun onVideoSizeChanged(width: Int, height: Int) {
        //super.onVideoSizeChanged(width, height)
    }
    ...
}
```